# Getting second operation Db context after second request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core MVC application and I have a view who do a post request as:

```
  $.ajax({
                    url:'/Advertisers/ActiveAdvertiser?id='+id+'&isActive='+!isActive,
                    method: 'POST',
                    success: function(r){
                        Swal.fire("Inactivated!", "Advertiser inactivated successfully", "success");
                    },
                    error: function (request) {
                        console.log(request.responseText)
                        Swal.fire("Error!", "Something went wrong, please try again`", "warning");
                    }
                });
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> ActiveAdvertiser(int id, bool isActive)
{
    var advertiser = await _advertisersService.GetAdvertiserByAdvertiserIdAsync(id);

    if (advertiser != null)
    {
        var model = AssingAdvertiserViewModel(advertiser, id);
        model.IsActive = isActive;

        var result = await _advertisersService.UpdateAdvertiserAsync(model, GetCurrentUserAsync().Id);

        if (result != null)
        {
            return Json(new { result = "OK" });
        }
    }

    return Json(new { result = "BadRequest" });
}
```

Post method services:

```
public Task<Advertiser?> GetAdvertiserByAdvertiserIdAsync(int advertiserId)
{
    return _db.Advertisers
              .Include(a => a.Address)
              .Include(pc => pc.PrimaryContact)
              .Include(ac => ac.AlternateContact)
              .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.AdvertiserId == advertiserId);
}

private AdvertiserViewModel AssingAdvertiserViewModel(Advertiser advertiser, int id)
{
    var model = new AdvertiserViewModel()
    {
        //Fill model here
    };

    return model;
}

public async Task<Advertiser?> UpdateAdvertiserAsync(AdvertiserViewModel model, int updatedById)
{
    var advertiser = await GetAdvertiserByAdvertiserIdAsync(model.AdvertiserId);

    if (advertiser is null)
        return null;

    advertiser.Name = model.Name;

    // fill model here

    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return advertiser;
}
```

The problem is I do the first request, and it returns Success with any issues, but if I try to do a second one, it throws an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation was started on
> this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is
> usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same
> instance of DbContext.

If I stop the project and run it again it works one time again and in the second time get the error again

I read about this issue in other questions, and apparently is because you don't use the await services, I check my code and almost everything uses await. Can someone see something that I don't see? Regards

Comment: Most likely a missing `await` when calling an `async` method. The problem could be anywhere though.

Comment: I assume that `_advertisersService` is initialized from an DI injected instance. If so, how is the type of `_advertisersService` registered in the DI container (singleton, scoped, transient)?

Comment: With transient `services.AddTransient<IAdvertisersService, AdvertisersService>();` @Christian.K

Answer (score 0):

You could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#avoiding-dbcontext-threading-issues) for how to handle this error:

**Therefore, always await async calls immediately, or use separate DbContext instances for operations that execute in parallel.**

So you could check if misssing the await keyword on  async operation

and  use separate Dbcontext instances with DbcontextFactory as below:

regist the factory in service collection:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<SomeContext>();
```

inject it into controller/Service/Somewhereelse:

```
public class SomeEntitiesController : Controller
        {
            
            private readonly IDbContextFactory<SomeContext> _factory;
            public SomeEntitiesController(IDbContextFactory<SomeContext> factory)
            {
                
                _factory = factory;
            }
          }
```

create a new dbcontext:

```
_factory.CreateDbContext()
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by adding `ServiceLifetime.Transient` into my services as:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
            options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationDbConnection")),
            ServiceLifetime.Transient
        );
```